# Displaying dynamic data from an csv file

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium and Python to scrape the 1s eth price from Binance. The Scraper is getting the 1s price and storing it in a CSV file. My goal is to display the data which is constantly being updated in the CSV file to be updated in a simple HTML page. Pretty much like Binance is doing it, but simpler. For some reason, the index page updates, but the p tag doesn't update with the data in the CSV file. I think the problem is with my JavaScript. I guess It's not getting the data because it can't recognize my Python file or read it.

This is my Index file which includes Javascript. Just some basic HTML and some JavaScript that should get the data from the CSV file and update it every 1s, but doesn't

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>

    <p id="eth_eur_1s">0</p>

    <script>
        function startLiveUpdate () {
            
            const ethPrice = document.getElementById('eth_eur_1s');


            setInterval(function() {
                fetch('Etherium_USDT_1s.csv').then(function (response) {

                    return response.json();

                }) .then(function (data) {

                    ethPrice.textContent = data.eth_eur_1s;

                }) .catch(function(error){

                    console.log("Error");

                });

            }, 1000);
            
            
        }

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

            startLiveUpdate();

        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my Python file. Just gets the 1s price from the Binance and prints it to my empty csv file.

```
import os
import time
import pandas
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options() 
options.add_argument("--headless=new") 


os.environ['PATH'] += r"C:/SeleniumDrivers" # path to driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options) 
driver.get("https://www.binance.com/en/trade/ETH_USDT?_from=markets&theme=dark&type=spot") 

eth_price = []


while True: 
    
    price = driver.execute_script("""
      return document.querySelector('.showPrice').innerText
    """)
    
    eth_price.append(price)
    
    df = pandas.DataFrame({'eth_price':eth_price})
    
    df.to_csv('Etherium_USDT_1s.csv', index=False)
    time.sleep(1)
    print(df)
```

I know It's possible through ajax or something that can use dynamic information, but I just need some guidance on how. I appreciate any help :) Thanks

Comment: Did you look into CSV  file? I expect it does NOT have JSON format. So why do you use `return response.json();` in code ? This will cause an error which will be catched and reported to the console. Did you control console output? Don't forget to write output and error details in your question, because they are important.